# LINQ Issue, Dragging stored procedure returns int rather than Result

Tags: linq-to-sql, c#-2.0

This is the stored procedure.

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UserSearch]
(
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
    Id              INT,
    UserName        INT,
    StatusId        INT
)

INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT userId, userName, statusId FROM [User]

SELECT  UserId,
        COUNT(ISNULL(StatusId, 0)) AS UserCount,
        StatusTypeName
FROM  @temp
GROUP BY StatusTypeId, StatusTypeName
```

When i run this then it works fine. Yesterday when i drag this stored procedure in the method pane in dbml file then it doesn't create UserSearchResult class and it returns int rather than ISingleResult. But today in the morning i have dragged it again and now it has created the class and also returns ISingleResult, which is correct. But i am too much confuse with the linq behavior why this occur? It waste my time too much.

Answer (score 1):

When that happens to me depends on the access level that the connection has on the Stored Procedure. If you don't have execution access it will return an integer because a Stored Procedure always return an integer.

Also it can be related to not having the SELECT statement(s) at the end of your stored procedure, because it uses those statements to figure out the result types.

Hope this helps